# Parasitic capacitance of a chip

Tags: transistors, frequency, parasitic-capacitance

I know that the parasitic capacitance of a chip is pronounced Cdyn.
If I apply on some scenario one the chip which will toggle the all of its transistors with two different voltages, but the frequency is the same, does the Cdyn will be the same?

Comment: The dynamic capacitance remains the same.

Comment: Why there is no impact from the voltage applied on the chip?

Comment: Can you help explaining via equations?